# Problem running document with IEEEtran class

Tags: errors, ieeetran

I have installed MiKTeX and WinEDT on my laptop. when I am trying to compile my files the below errors (see at the end of the log file, undefined control sequence) are appeared. Basically, I am sure that there is nothing wrong with my files since I can run and get the pdf file when I am compiling them on my friend's MiKTeX software. I would very much appreciate if someone help me to go through this.

_______________________________________________________ my `log` file report

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.3.4)  12 MAR 2015 17:30
entering extended mode
**"C:/Users/Morteza/Desktop/ICC_2015-2015-03-02/ICC 2015/ICC_2015_Final_1702201
5/ZD_JSCC_Final.tex"

("C:/Users/Morteza/Desktop/ICC_2015-2015-03-02/ICC 2015/ICC_2015_Final_17022015
/ZD_JSCC_Final.tex"
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 68 languages loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ieeetran\IEEEtran.cls"
Document Class: IEEEtran 2014/09/17 V1.8a by Michael Shell
-- See the "IEEEtran_HOWTO" manual for usage information.
-- http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenA=\dimen102
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenB=\dimen103
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenC=\dimen104
\@IEEEtrantmpcountA=\count79
\@IEEEtrantmpcountB=\count80
\@IEEEtrantmpcountC=\count81
\@IEEEtrantmptoksA=\toks14
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+ptm on input line 458.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\psnfss\ot1ptm.fd"
File: ot1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
)
-- Using 8.5in x 11in (letter) paper.
-- Using PDF output.
\@IEEEnormalsizeunitybaselineskip=\dimen105
-- This is a 10 point document.
\CLASSINFOnormalsizebaselineskip=\dimen106
\CLASSINFOnormalsizeunitybaselineskip=\dimen107
\IEEEnormaljot=\dimen108
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <5> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1039.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <5> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1039.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <7> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1039.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <7> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1039.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <8> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1039.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <8> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1039.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <9> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1039.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <9> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1039.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1039.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1039.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <11> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1039.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <11> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1039.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1039.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1039.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <17> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1039.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <17> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1039.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <20> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1039.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <20> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1039.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <24> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1039.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <24> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1039.

\IEEEquantizedlength=\dimen109
\IEEEquantizedlengthdiff=\dimen110
\IEEEquantizedtextheightdiff=\dimen111
\IEEEilabelindentA=\dimen112
\IEEEilabelindentB=\dimen113
\IEEEilabelindent=\dimen114
\IEEEelabelindent=\dimen115
\IEEEdlabelindent=\dimen116
\IEEElabelindent=\dimen117
\IEEEiednormlabelsep=\dimen118
\IEEEiedmathlabelsep=\dimen119
\IEEEiedtopsep=\skip41
\c@section=\count82
\c@subsection=\count83
\c@subsubsection=\count84
\c@paragraph=\count85
\c@IEEEsubequation=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip42
\belowcaptionskip=\skip43
\c@figure=\count87
\c@table=\count88
\@IEEEeqnnumcols=\count89
\@IEEEeqncolcnt=\count90
\@IEEEsubeqnnumrollback=\count91
\@IEEEquantizeheightA=\dimen120
\@IEEEquantizeheightB=\dimen121
\@IEEEquantizeheightC=\dimen122
\@IEEEquantizeprevdepth=\dimen123
\@IEEEquantizemultiple=\count92
\@IEEEquantizeboxA=\box26
\@IEEEtmpitemindent=\dimen124
\c@IEEEbiography=\count93
\@IEEEtranrubishbin=\box27
) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def"
File: t1enc.def 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 43.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+ptm on input line 100.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\psnfss\t1ptm.fd"
File: t1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for T1/ptm.
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty"
Package: inputenc 2014/04/30 v1.2b Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks15
\inpenc@posthook=\toks16

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\latin1.def"
File: latin1.def 2014/04/30 v1.2b Input encoding file
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty"
Package: geometry 2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks17
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty"
Package: ifvtex 2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\Gm@cnth=\count94
\Gm@cntv=\count95
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count96
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen125
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen126
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen127
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen128
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen129
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen130
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen131
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen132
\Gm@dimlist=\toks18

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.cfg"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amscls\amsthm.sty"
Package: amsthm 2009/07/02 v2.20.1
\thm@style=\toks19
\thm@bodyfont=\toks20
\thm@headfont=\toks21
\thm@notefont=\toks22
\thm@headpunct=\toks23
\thm@preskip=\skip44
\thm@postskip=\skip45
\thm@headsep=\skip46
\dth@everypar=\toks24
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty"
Package: amsmath 2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip47

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty"
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty"
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0
\@emptytoks=\toks25
\ex@=\dimen133
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty"
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d
\pmbraise@=\dimen134
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty"
Package: amsopn 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count97
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 210.
\uproot@=\count98
\leftroot@=\count99
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 306.
\classnum@=\count100
\DOTSCASE@=\count101
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 378.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 381.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 466.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box28
\strutbox@=\box29
\big@size=\dimen135
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 566.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 567.
\macc@depth=\count102
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count103
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count104
\dspbrk@lvl=\count105
\tag@help=\toks26
\row@=\count106
\column@=\count107
\maxfields@=\count108
\andhelp@=\toks27
\eqnshift@=\dimen136
\alignsep@=\dimen137
\tagshift@=\dimen138
\tagwidth@=\dimen139
\totwidth@=\dimen140
\lineht@=\dimen141
\@envbody=\toks28
\multlinegap=\skip48
\multlinetaggap=\skip49
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks29
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2665.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2666.
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amssymb.sty"
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amsfonts.sty"
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 91.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count109
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen142
\Gin@req@width=\dimen143
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\epstopdf.sty"
Package: epstopdf 2010/02/09 v2.5 Conversion with epstopdf on the fly (HO)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty"
Package: epstopdf-base 2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\grfext.sty"
Package: grfext 2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvdefinekeys.sty"
Package: kvdefinekeys 2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty"
Package: pdftexcmds 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 452.
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty"
Package: hyperref 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.sty"
Package: hobsub-hyperref 2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)


("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty"
Package: hobsub-generic 2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
Package: hobsub 2012/04/25 v1.12 Construct package bundles (HO)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `infwarerr' (already loaded).
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ltxcmds' (already loaded).
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ifluatex' (already loaded).
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ifvtex' (already loaded).
Package: intcalc 2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ifpdf' (already loaded).
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `etexcmds' (already loaded).
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `kvsetkeys' (already loaded).
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `kvdefinekeys' (already loaded).
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `pdftexcmds' (already loaded).
Package: pdfescape 2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
Package: bigintcalc 2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
Package: bitset 2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
Package: uniquecounter 2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `hobsub' (already loaded).
Package: letltxmacro 2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
Package: hopatch 2011/06/24 v1.1 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
Package: xcolor-patch 2011/01/30 xcolor patch
Package: atveryend 2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
Package atveryend Info: \enddocument detected (standard20110627).
Package: atbegshi 2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
Package: refcount 2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
Package: hycolor 2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty"
Package: auxhook 2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen144
\Hy@linkcounter=\count110
\Hy@pagecounter=\count111

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def"
File: pd1enc.def 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count112

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg"
File: hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
)
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4443.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4448.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4451.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4458.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4463.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4688.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count113

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\url\url.sty"
\Urlmuskip=\muskip11
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5041.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen145
\Fld@menulength=\count114
\Field@Width=\dimen146
\Fld@charsize=\dimen147
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6295.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6300.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6303.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6310.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6315.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6320.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6325.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6365.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6369.
\Hy@abspage=\count115
\c@Item=\count116
\c@Hfootnote=\count117
)

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hpdftex.def"
File: hpdftex.def 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
\Fld@listcount=\count118
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count119

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty"
Package: rerunfilecheck 2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
82.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip50
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\cite\cite.sty"
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 302.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nocite on input line 373.
Package: cite 2010/09/10  v 5.3
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\soul\soul.sty"
Package: soul 2003/11/17 v2.4 letterspacing/underlining (mf)
\SOUL@word=\toks30
\SOUL@lasttoken=\toks31
\SOUL@cmds=\toks32
\SOUL@buffer=\toks33
\SOUL@token=\toks34
\SOUL@spaceskip=\skip51
\SOUL@ttwidth=\dimen148
\SOUL@uldp=\dimen149
\SOUL@ulht=\dimen150
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\color.sty"
Package: color 2014/10/28 v1.1a Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package color Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 137.
)
\c@thm=\count120

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\babel\babel.sty"
Package: babel 2014/09/25 3.9l The Babel package

*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\bblopts.cfg"
File: bblopts.cfg 2006/07/31 v1.0 MiKTeX 'babel' configuration
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\babel-english\english.ldf"
Language: english 2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\babel\babel.def"
File: babel.def 2014/09/25 3.9l Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count121
\U@D=\dimen151
)
\l@canadian = a dialect from \language\l@american 
\l@australian = a dialect from \language\l@british 
\l@newzealand = a dialect from \language\l@british 
))
(ZD_JSCC_Final.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ptm/bx/n' in size <5> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ptm/bx/it' in size <5> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ptm/bx/n' in size <7> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ptm/bx/it' in size <7> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ptm/bx/n' in size <8> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ptm/bx/it' in size <8> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ptm/bx/n' in size <9> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ptm/bx/it' in size <9> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ptm/bx/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ptm/bx/it' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ptm/bx/n' in size <11> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ptm/bx/it' in size <11> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ptm/bx/n' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ptm/bx/it' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ptm/bx/n' in size <17> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ptm/bx/it' in size <17> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ptm/bx/n' in size <20> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ptm/bx/it' in size <20> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ptm/bx/n' in size <24> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ptm/bx/it' in size <24> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 32.

-- Lines per column: 56 (approximate, difference = 7.33865pt).
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: <default>
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(46.97505pt, 520.3449pt, 46.97505pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(50.58878pt, 679.33865pt, 65.04256pt)
* \paperwidth=614.295pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=520.3449pt
* \textheight=679.33865pt
* \oddsidemargin=-25.29494pt
* \evensidemargin=-25.29494pt
* \topmargin=-52.24883pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=18.56761pt
* \topskip=12.0pt
* \footskip=40.5821pt
* \marginparwidth=20.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=12.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.79993pt plus 4.79993pt minus 2.39996pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumntrue
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count122
\scratchdimen=\dimen152
\scratchbox=\box30
\nofMPsegments=\count123
\nofMParguments=\count124
\everyMPshowfont=\toks35
\MPscratchCnt=\count125
\MPscratchDim=\dimen153
\MPnumerator=\count126
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count127
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks36
)
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box31
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 32.
 ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty"
Package: nameref 2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty"
Package: gettitlestring 2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count128
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 32.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 32.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 32.

(ZD_JSCC_Final.out) (ZD_JSCC_Final.out)
\@outlinefile=\write3

! Undefined control sequence.
\@author ->\authorblockN 
                         {Morteza Varasteh$^*$, Deniz G\"{u}nd\"{u}z$^*$ and...
l.41 \begin
           {abstract}
? 
! Emergency stop.
\@author ->\authorblockN 
                         {Morteza Varasteh$^*$, Deniz G\"{u}nd\"{u}z$^*$ and...
l.41 \begin
           {abstract}
End of file on the terminal!
```

Comment: ad  `\listfiles` to the document then look at the file list at the end of the log, compare with the result on the other machine, one of you will have a different version of some package.

Comment: Try to isolate the problem by producing a minimal file that still exhibits your problem yet is small enough to investigate the matter further ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)). Can you compile other documents fine?

Comment: Your friend has probably an older system. In the newest version of ieeetran.cls `\authorblockN` is no longer defined. Use `\IEEEauthorblockN` instead, see the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Just to end this:

Installing MiKTeX new does **not** mean that you have an **current** version running.  As you can read in the documentation of MiKTeX you should after the installation run the MiKTeX package manager to **make sure that all installed package are in the current version**. (Or in other words: The install program does not knows about new packages since the installer was created. The package manager does this job!)

You said that on another MiKTeX system your document can be compiled without errors.  That indicates different versions of installed packages.

With `\listfiles` (see comment of David Carlisle) you get an list in your log file with the used packages and their versions. Compare this list with the list on the other computer. You will see the differences!

At the end of your log file you have

> ! Undefined control
>   sequence. \@author ->\authorblockN

As mentioned by Ulrike Fischer document class `ieeetran.cls` has changed (you remember `\listfiles`here?) and command  `\authorblockN` is no longer defined. Use `\IEEEauthorblockN` instead, as descibed in the documentation.